# Print values per unique value from dataframe in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a list of attachments (.pdf files) in a folder and another dataframe with name and values. Each name may have multiple rows if the name has multiple values.

I want to print out the values corresponding to each name in a loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name': ["Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Jack", "Jack"], 
                          'Value': ['a','b','c','a','nan']})
```

I tried these two loops:

```
for i in df0['Name'].unique():
    print(df['Values'][df['Name'] == i], '\n')

for i,j in df.groupby('Name'):
    print(df['Values'][df['Name'] == i])
```

where each "printout" is a series. Instead I want to print out each data value for each name but "grouped".

For example:

```
Peter:
a
b
c
```

next

```
Jack:
a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want for each loop one column DataFrame with column name like group name use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
for i,j in df.groupby('Name'):
    print(j['Value'].to_frame(i))
```

Or:

```
for i,j in df.groupby('Name')['Value']:
    print(j.to_frame(i))
```

Comment: Is it possible to print out each value as string? I get `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`? Because when I put the values in a list, the values come out as string.

Comment: @Mataunited18 - Do you think `print(j['Value'].to_frame(i).to_string(index=False))` ?

Comment: all the values get bundled together in one string. Is it possible that each value get printed out as string instead of combining them together?

Comment: @Mataunited18 0 What about change `print(j['Value'].to_frame(i))` to `s = j['Value']` and then `for val in s: print (val)` ?